# Question on calculating hypercohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, quasicoherent-sheaves, sheaf-cohomology

I want to compute the algebraic de Rham cohomology of $ \mathbb{C}^* $, and I'm confused. I don't have much background in this, so I was hoping a very concrete example would clear up a lot of this confusion. So far:

We have this cochain of  $ \mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$-modules:

$0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}] \longrightarrow {\Omega}_{\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]/\mathbb{C}}^1 \longrightarrow 0$

where ${\Omega}_{\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]/\mathbb{C}}^1 = \mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}] dx $.    (as i understand)

As I understand, to obtain the de Rham cohomology we want a Cartan–Eilenberg resolution for this cochain, and then we want a left exact functor $F: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is our module category.

Then we want to compute  the total cohomology of $F(I)$, where $I$ is our resolution.

My issue seems to be actually doing this stuff, do I need to find $I,F$ explicitly? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If anyone knows a text where they do this for some very simple affine space that would really help as well

Comment: If you don't have the background, then why are you trying to do this? First things first: the functor $F$ you are supposed to be thinking about is the global sections functor. Second:  cohomology of quasicoherent sheaves on affine schemes is trivial, so hypercohomology reduces to ordinary cohomology in this case.

Comment: thanks for the help.

I'm learning the background as I go. I'm doing a sort of summer project, and I'm currently reading through weibel's book, which i'm finding very good.

So are you saying if I went about the process of calculating the hyper, it would come out to the cohomology of the original chain? If so I'd still like to try and calculate it this longer way to get my head around the method. I'm going to move to non-affine examples after I've done this.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ah I see, ok, I'm going to go back through the book on global sections functors.

Comment: You won't really find the necessary background on quasicoherent sheaves in Weibel. Try Hartshorne, or any algebraic geometry textbook.

Comment: I'll definitely look at Hartshorne. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a smooth  affine scheme $X$  of finite type over $\mathbb C$ the de Rham cohomology $H^*_{dR}(X)$ is just the cohomology of the complex of global differential forms: $$  H^*_{dR}(X)=H^*(\Gamma(X,\Omega^*_X))        $$
In your case you have to compute the cohomology of the complex  $$0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}] \stackrel {d}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]\cdot dx \longrightarrow 0$$ and you immediately get: $$H^0_{dR}(X)=\mathbb C,\quad   H^1_{dR}(X)=\mathbb C \cdot \frac {dx}{x}\cong \mathbb C, \quad  H^i_{dR}(X)=0  \quad \text {for}  \quad  i\geq 2          $$  This is in line with the fact that algebraic cohomology coincides with the classical topology  of the underlying complex holomorphic manifold $X^h$:  $$H^*_{dR}(X)=H^*(X^h,\mathbb C)$$

**Bibliography** [Read the Master !](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Farchive.numdam.org%2Farticle%2FPMIHES_1966__29__95_0.pdf&ei=01nNU4ORIuXb0QXWyIGgDw&usg=AFQjCNEBvfQ-WJu4Q18Pop7Zl68I6swFjg&sig2=oTpUTTjx0PVNW4evIHgY_A)

Comment: sweet! thanks so much

Comment: @JC574 I will add, just for a comment, that the reason that the hypercohomology is just the cohomology, is because the resolving objects are acyclic. Hypercohomology is supposed to compute the cohomology of an object from any resolution, acyclic or not. But, if the resolution is already acyclic, hypercohomology just does what you would have done before you needed any of this advanced machinery--take global sections and take cohomology.

Comment: I might try a more complicated case later, and add my working in to my question

Comment: Great reference Georges!